# How to display all values of a json?

Tags: javascript, json, api

I'm returning a JSON from the MercadoLivre API. In it I receive the following structure:

```
{
"seller_id": "239258430",
"query": null,
"paging": {
"total": 6241,
"offset": 0,
"limit": 100
}
```

I need to get all datas, not the only 100th firsts, I try set limit with my `'total'` but that not works. Any Suggestion?

I need record that in my Database.

Comment: What endpoint are you hitting? Can you show us what your request looks like?

Comment: Sure! Here: https://api.mercadolibre.com/users/239258430/items/search?status=active&access_token=APP_USR-7289461436586299-051507-c3ea046723423558eb827292c5b0cd2__N_K__-239258430&limit=100&offset=600

Comment: That's not my access token, I modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the documentation is quite clear if [you read it](http://developers.mercadolibre.com/paging-results/).

Secondly, mercadolibre apis have [their own custom developer forum](http://developers-forum.mercadolibre.com/index.php/forum/2-items/) :

Anyway, the answer would be that you need to send offset to get paginated results. Always keep in mind that in searches, your limit can´t be higher than 200. So to get results from 200 to 400, you should add &offset=200&limit=200 to your query

Comment: The forum is not always active, most of the questions are ignored, and the documentation in Portuguese is confusing, I thought I had no problem dealing with the subject here, anyway, thank you!

Comment: @ViniciusRosa yeah its not very active but there are a lot of examples where people might have asked the same question. If you don´t know portuguese or spanish it´s quite difficult to understand yeah, but at least de api documentation is in english. Anyway, if you ever ask here a mercadolibre api question, tag me so I can look at it. I use them a lot at work